# How to pass credentials for BASIC Auth to browser?

Tags: xmlhttprequest, basic-authentication

I know that when the browser sees a `WWW-Authenticate` header with the value `Basic`, it will bring up the login dialog box. If the login succeeds, the browser pretty much handles the credentials via the `Authorization` header it will send automatically in future requests.

I want to use my own login screen but I want the browser to handle the credentials passed in as if they were passed via the browsers dialog box. Is there a way to pass these credentials to the browser this way or do I have to manually add the `Authorization` header myself if I use my own login screen?

Answer (score 1):

After successful login, redirect user to

http://username:password@www.yoursite.com/